# reverse_geocoder on python with panda

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, reverse-geocoding

I am currently using this code to go through a file and get the district however it takes forever to execute since I have 118185 rows of data to go through.
Is there another way to use `reverse_geocoder` that doesn't take that long

```
df["coord"]=list(zip(df["pickup_latitude"],df["pickup_longitude"]))
list1 = []
for x,y in df["coord"]: 
    coordinates=(x,y)
    newItem = rg.search(coordinates)[0].get('admin2')
    list1.append(newItem)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [PyData 2015 demo notebook](https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder/blob/master/notebook/PyData%202015.ipynb) in the `reverse_geocoder` GitHub repository, you can pass a tuple of tuples into `rg.search()` to process multiple coordinate pairs at once.

```
# Convert lat and long columns to a tuple of tuples
coords = tuple(zip(df['pickup_latitude'], df['pickup_longitude']))

results_rg = rg.search(coords)
results_admin2 = [x.get('admin2') for x in results_rg]

# Optional: insert admin2 results into new df column
df['admin2'] = results_admin2
```

If this is still too slow, you can try a simple speed test by using only the first few rows of `df`. For example, to run the above code on the first 1000 rows of the DataFrame, change the first line to this:

```
coords = tuple(zip(df['pickup_latitude'].iloc[:1000], 
                   df['pickup_longitude'].iloc[:1000]))
```